# jQuery: How to read the dynamically changed image source?

Tags: jquery, image, dynamic, src

When the user clicks on **"banner"** class first time the sources of images are examined in "if" statement and get changed perfectly. Now the issue is when user clicks on **"banner"** class again, it does not come to "else" block because its not reading the dynamically changed sources. What is the solution for this?

```
$(function() {

  $('.banner').click(function(){     

    if($("#left").attr('src',"img/unSelectedBanner.jpg") && 
       $("#right").attr('src',"img/unSelectedLogo.jpg"))
       {
          $("#left").attr('src',"img/SelectedBanner.jpg");
          $("#right").attr('src',"img/SelectedLogo.jpg");
       } 
       else if($("#left").attr('src',"img/SelectedBanner.jpg") && 
               $("#rightARM").attr('src',"BodyImage/rightArmSelected.png"))
               {
                  $("#leftARM").attr('src',"BodyImage/leftArm.png");
                  $("#rightARM").attr('src',"BodyImage/rightArm.png");
               }    
  });

});
```

Comment: use `$('.banner').on('click',function(){` Or `$(document).on('click','.banner',function(){`.Try and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not comparing the content of the attribute with a string, you are checking if **setting** the attribute returns true / false.

so instead of:-

```
if($("#left").attr('src',"img/unSelectedBanner.jpg")) { ... }
```

you should use

```
if($("#left").attr('src') == "img/unSelectedBanner.jpg") { ... }
```

same with all the other checks.

Comment: Worked for me. Cheers !!